# How to get Eclipselink Entity Manager?

Tags: java, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I'm working on a C/S java project and try to use Eclipselink to do the ORM(client side cache database,derby).
It's quite easy to do the query with examples & expressions, but when it comes to insert/update, i found that Entity Manager should be used(I'm quite new in java ORM, maybe there's another way?).
When i try to create em, it always throw a Exception that telling me i need a server session(i.e. can not find the persistence-unit by name).
When i use session bean & @PersistenceUnit annotation, it returns a Null.

Did I make some stupid mistakes? Or does there any easy way to Update/Insert values? I supposed that there may be some way like session.save(Object) or something like that which can makes this work simple.

EDIT: I'v tried to use UnitOfWork, but get "Attempt to modify an identity column" error, should i change map file or something that make Eclipselink recognize the identity PK?

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

Add this line in POJO do not work.

**EDIT**:I've tried use Unit of work to insert value here's the code

```
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory("default");
    Session session = sessionFactory.getSharedSession();
    UnitOfWork uow = session.acquireUnitOfWork();
    SysUser usr2 = new SysUser();
    usr2.setUserName("test");
    usr2.setUserPassword("test");
    uow.registerObject(usr2);
    uow.commit();
```

But it result in a

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Attempt to modify an identity column 'DB_ID'.
```

here's the annotation i used:

```
@Column(name = "DB_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
protected int dbId;
```

And for EntityManager:

```
<persistence-unit name="my-app-name">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>java:/app/jdbc/jdbc/ConnectionDerbyDS</jta-data-source>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use EclipseLink (via the JPA API) in a Java SE application, you have to set up things a little differently then when your app consists of components running in a Java EE container.

You get an `EntityManager` with lines like these:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("my-app");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

And your application needs to have a `persistence.xml` file in the `META-INF` directory of the JAR file of your application. You configure JPA in this file; things you put in there tell Java which persistence provider to use and what the connection parameters for your database are.

The persistence unit name (`"my-app"` in the example above) must be the same as the name specified in the `persistence-unit` element in `persistence.xml`.

See [this EclipseLink example](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/OutsideContainer), which shows what your `persistence.xml` has to look like.

`EntityManager` contains methods such as `persist(Object)` which you can use to save entities into the database (see [these examples](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI) that show how to use `EntityManager`).

Your entity POJO should have a column which will contain the entity id, and it must have a no-args constructor:

```
@Entity
public class Example {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    // ... Add other properties here

    // Required no-args constructor
    public Example() {
    }

    // ... Add getters and setters here
}
```

**Addition**

You can save an entity in the database using the `EntityManager` like in the following code. No need to use `UnitOfWork` (as far as I know, `UnitOfWork` is something you needed when using the older JPA 1.0 API; you don't need this for JPA 2.0):

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.persist(myEntity);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named my-app-name: Provider named org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider threw unexpected exception at create EntityManagerFactory: 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException`

Comment: @MikeZTM do you have all the necessary libraries in your classpath?

Comment: Also, don't use `jta-data-source` in your `persistence.xml` in a Java SE application - just specify the JDBC connection parameters (see [the example](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/OutsideContainer)).

Comment: I've already used javax.persistence.jdbc(this persistence.xml is auto generated by Toplink editor).Classpath seems correct(JDBC driver works well and "org.eclipse.presistence" classes was auto config by JDeveloper)

Comment: I checked the examples at Eclipsewiki and it suggest to use Unit of Work to do the insert/Update. I tried it and Update works well,but Insert have some problem with the IDENTITY column. should I post a new question for this(or just edit this question)?

Comment: @MikeZTM see my addition above.

Comment: I find that it seems UnitOfWork still works in JPA2.0. I checked all xml/java and quite confirmed that the name/class/xml were all cerrect but still could not create EntityManager. I even tried to get EM by JNDI lookup and `@PresistenceUnit`,but it returns null.

Comment: Maybe `UnitOfWork` still works in JPA 2.0, but why make it more complicated than necessary?

Comment: THX!! I just found out i missed a line about JTA in my presistence.xml,after delete it. the EM works. thx for ur help :-)